# How to invoke a million Lambdas efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which I'm currently invoking from EC2. But I'm invoking it sequentially in a loop. So, if there are 1000 items to be processed, I'm using a simple loop to iterate over them and invoke the Lambda function for each item.

If this were to be done for a million items, this will not be efficient. What options do I have to reduce the time taken for this process.

The process for all items are independent; so, I can invoke, say, 1000 Lambdas in 1000 threads. But is that appropriate? I don't know much about Celery, SQS, redis, etc. but will those be useful in this scenario?

Just in case it's relevant, each Lambda takes around 5 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice is to **push messages to an Amazon SQS queue** and configure the queue to **trigger an AWS Lambda function**.

You can push up to 10 messages at a time to the SQS queue.

This approach also has the benefit of handling failed invocations by moving messages to a Dead Letter Queue.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using a **message broker** would be more efficient. You can got with **Redis or RabbitMQ**